# Polar curvature

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, curvature

To find curvature in polar coordinates, is it the same formula as in rectangular but like with $dr/d\theta$ instead of $dy/dx$?

Comment: **Note**: For a plane curve in a polar coordinates $\rho=g(\varphi)$, we can use this expression for curvature $K$:

$K=\frac{\rho^2+2\rho'^2-\rho\rho''}{(\rho^2+\rho'^2)^{3/2}}$

Answer (score 2):

No. For $\gamma(\theta)=(x(\theta),y(\theta))$ you know that $$\kappa(\theta) =\frac{x'(\theta)y''(\theta)-x''(\theta)y'(\theta)}{(x'(\theta)^2+y'(\theta)^2)^{3/2}}.$$Write $x(\theta)=r(\theta)\cos\theta$, $y(\theta)=r(\theta)\sin\theta$, differentiate and plug above to get the correct formula for the curvature in polar coordinates.

Comment: Okay, but what if I just want the curvature of $r$ with respect to $\theta$?

Comment: That's what I gave you, read carefully. What I wrote is, in polar form, $r=r(\theta)$.

Comment: You wrote $k(\theta)$ though. The coordinates are mixed on the right-hand side. If you wrote an expression where the left hand side contained an invertible expression only in terms of $r$ and the other side contained an invertible expression only in terms of $\theta,$ then that would answer the question.

Comment: Again, a parametrization for $r = r(\theta)$ in rectangular coordinates is $x(\theta) = r(\theta)\cos\theta$ and $y(\theta)=r(\theta)\sin\theta$. So applying the rectangular formula for that gives the polar formula.

Comment: Alright, thank you.