# general parametric form of curvature in polar coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, curvature

I saw this in another question

$$\kappa(\theta) =\frac{x'(\theta)y''(\theta)-x''(\theta)y'(\theta)}{(x'(\theta)^2+y'(\theta)^2)^{3/2}}$$
[Polar curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836747/polar-curvature)

I know that the general form of parametric curve for polar as fallow

$$ <r\cos(t),  r\sin(t)> $$

what is the curvature form of polar equation
$$ r = \cos(5\theta) $$

Comment: **Hint**: For a plane curve in polar coordinates $\rho=g(\varphi)$, we can use this expression for curvature $K$:

$K=\frac{\rho^2+2\rho'^2-\rho\rho''}{(\rho^2+\rho'^2)^{3/2}}$.

Comment: I want it for cos(5theta)

Comment: To @AoBo: I used $\rho$ and $\varphi$, i.e $\rho=\cos(5\varphi)$. Can you find $\rho'$, $\rho''$?

Comment: ok. Yes I can do that.

Comment: Nice! Next, it should be:

$K=\frac{38-12\cos(10\varphi)}{(13-12\cos(10\varphi))^{3/2}}$.

Comment: Hey I did that but can You show your work on pice of paper.

Comment: Paper is easier than typing, you know.

Comment: To @AoBo: my work is given as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: For a plane curve in a polar coordinates $\rho = g(\varphi)$, we can use this expression for curvature $K$:
$$
K=\frac{\rho^2+2\rho'^2-\rho\rho''}{(\rho^2+\rho'^2)^{3/2}}.
$$
We have $\rho=\cos(5\varphi)$, so $\rho'=-5\sin(5\varphi)$ and $\rho''=-25\cos(5\varphi)$, hence it will hold:
$$
\begin{align}
K = & \frac{\cos^2(5\varphi)+50\sin^2(5\varphi)+25\cos^2(5\varphi)}{(\cos^2(5\varphi)+25\sin^2(5\varphi))^{3/2}}=\frac{26\cos^2(5\varphi)+50\sin^2(5\varphi)}{(\cos^2(5\varphi)+25\sin^2(5\varphi))^{3/2}}\\
 &\\
= &\frac{38\cos^2(5\varphi)-12\cos^2(5\varphi)+38\sin^2(5\varphi)+12\sin^2(5\varphi)}{(13\cos^2(5\varphi)-12\cos^2(5\varphi)+13\sin^2(5\varphi)+12\sin^2(5\varphi))^{3/2}}\\
 &\\
= & \frac{38-12(\cos^2(5\varphi)-\sin^2(5\varphi))}{(13-12(\cos^2(5\varphi)-\sin^2(5\varphi)))^{3/2}}\\
 &\\
= & \boxed{\frac{38-12\cos(10\varphi)}{(13-12\cos(10\varphi))^{3/2}}}.
\end{align}
$$